# Perl, print a letter after a constant format with sprintf()

Tags: perl, printf

So I'm trying to format a string with sprintf and I have a variable format setup for multiple use. But using it in my sprintf I cannot figure out how to print a letter after it without a Perl concatenation '.' which I feel is mixing two types of formatting and not the best for readability, or maintainability.

Example of what I mean is

```
my $seconds_resolution= '%.4f';
my $seconds = 5.12345;

say sprintf("$seconds_resolutions" , $seconds);
```

Throws an error

```
my $seconds_resolution= '%.4f';
my $seconds = 5.12345;
say sprintf("$seconds_resolution s" , $seconds);
```

Doesn't make sense to the user for a space to be there

```
my $seconds_resolution= '%.4f';
my $seconds = 5.12345;
say sprintf($seconds_resolution .'s' , $seconds);
```

And this is really hard to read

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue in interpolation, you can simply wrap your variable name in braces to separate it from strings that are not a part of the variable's name:

```
my $seconds_resolution= '%.4f';
my $seconds = 5.12345;

say sprintf("${seconds_resolution}s" , $seconds);
```

without the braces, Perl can't know where the variable name stops and bare words begin.

Another approach would be to include the `s` in your format string, then you don't have to worry about interpolation at all. Note: This is what your 3rd example is actually doing:

```
my $seconds_resolution= '%.4fs';
my $seconds = 5.12345;

say sprintf($seconds_resolution, $seconds);
```

Also, in case you aren't already (I don't see them in your example), you should  always enable [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html)

Comment: Minor, but `say sprintf $fmt, $foo` is probably better written `printf "$fmt\n", $foo`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot fair point. I couldn't really tell how the data was going to be used after this, `say` could just be for testing, so I left it as is.

Comment: I use `say sprintf` all the time. Aside from the gains for one-liners in Windows, it's more consistent with the surrounding `say`.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation:

```
my $seconds_resolution = '%.4f';
sprintf "${seconds_resolution}s", $seconds
```

```
my $seconds_resolution = '%.4f';
sprintf $seconds_resolution."s", $seconds
```

Unit in format:

```
my $seconds_resolution = '%.4fs';
sprintf $seconds_resolution, $seconds
```

Variable unit:

```
my $seconds_resolution = '%.4f%s';
sprintf $seconds_resolution, $seconds, 's'
```